# I tried installing windows on my Ubuntu machine and couldn't, now I can't even run Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows, bios

I had ubuntu set up  on  my ssd, and tried to install windows over it and now I can't even run ubuntu. I'm not sure what I should do, with  no usbs in I cant get past BIOS (Gigabyte). I'm not  good with BIOS to start  with, but ubuntu is coming  up in  my boot sequence but  my pc won't boot from it?

I hope  I'm  making sense, appreciate any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

For installing Windows by removing Ubuntu follow this steps:

1. Take a backup of your data to external drive.
2. Reboot the PC.
3. Insert Windows CD/Pendrive and select boot device as same.
4. When you see the "Windows Setup window". Press Shift + F10 keys together on the keyboard, which will take you to command prompt. Enter `DISKPART` command
5. Enter `list disk` command to list the available disks along with your CD/Pendrive.
6. Enter `select DiskX` command- here X is your disk number(Mostly which has large size).
7. Enter `clean` command (If it doesn't work enter `diskclean`), which erases all the data then exit the terminal.
8. Install OS by doing partitions (follow the steps in https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/install-windows-10.html).

Comment: OP writes that he tried to install Windows OVER Ubuntu. That is he tried to overwrite Ubuntu, which is perfectly legal.

Comment: modified answer